# dynamically creating entry in drop down box using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Js code

```
var ref =dojo.byId("xyz");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text="txt"
optn.value="val"
ref.options.add(optn);
```

I want dojo equivalent of above code